# How do I force Google Now to show updates from certain websites?

Tags: google-now

Google Now gives me updates for blogs that I visit regularly. But it's not very predictable in which websites it monitors. I see cards for SMBC and Channelate regularly, but not for xkcd. How can I teach it to notify me for xkcd too?

Comment: Visiting xkcd more frequently would do it.

Comment: I visit xkcd just as often as I visit the others. Sometimes I get updates even from blogs I don't visit as often. I'm wondering if there is a surefire way to see updates from xkcd.